# DbUnit: insert data into DB2 database after turning of foreign keys

Tags: database, db2, dbunit

I'm trying to insert initial data into a DB2 database in DbUnit using `DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(...)` which works fine with some datasets. In order to insert some datasets however, I need to disable foreign key constraints first (because the tables in some datasets can be listed in a 'wrong' order).

I'm disabling the foreign key constraints with command `SET INTEGRITY FOR <table_name> OFF`, but when I try to insert the data after calling that command, I get this error:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=1;SCHEMA.TABLE, DRIVER=4.17.30
```

The [IBM error code explanation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_9.0.0/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n668.dita?lang=en) isn't much helpfull here. Is there something I need to do after setting integrity on a table and before inserting data into that table?

**EDIT:**

I found this in the documentation for the OFF statement: "Specifies that the tables are placed in set integrity pending state. Only very limited activity is allowed on a table that is in set integrity pending state."

If I understand it correctly, this means that when I turn off the integrity checks on a table, I cannot perform any write/modify operations on it! What's the point of turning the integrity check off then? I need to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not "*disabling the foreign key constraints with command SET INTEGRITY*". `SET INTEGRITY OFF` basically means "I'm not sure about the integrity of this table data, so I'd rather restrict access to it until I figure out what's wrong".

To temporary disable foreign key verification you might try `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER FOREIGN KEY bar NOT ENFORCED`.

Comment: Thanks this might work. But what I don't like about this approach is that 1: I have to somehow find out the names of the foreign key constraints and 2: I have to call this for each constraint on each table. There are currently more than 20 tables in my schema and most of them have more than 1 foreign key. So the result is that before inserting the data, I'd have to make 50 db requests just to turn off the foreign keys, insert the data and then make another 50 db requests to turn them back on. And then repeat all this for all xy tests. Isn't there a way to disable all the constraints at once?